# measure for face detection

Tags: opencv, detection, face-detection

Is there a way to measure the confidence of face detection. I have tried face detection followed by features(nose+eyes+mouth), this approach gives me false negatives. I am currently using opencv face detection methods.

Please do let me know if there is a way to measure the confidence of face detection.

Comment: there is an [overload to detectMultiScale](http://docs.opencv.org/ref/master/d1/de5/classcv_1_1CascadeClassifier.html#accf96d130d9f3cf4c58bf445b7861c19) that gives you rejectlevels and weights as well. CAVEAT: you need to set outputRejectLevels=true